# Can we figure out normal force acting on a body after it has collided?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

Let's say there are two bodies, one stationary and the other with a constant velocity. After they have collided, some momentum of the moving body will be transferred to the stationary body. This will result in a change in the momentum of the moving body.

With all this information, can we determine the normal force's magnitude on both bodies? Do we need any more data otherwise? Will the coefficient of restitution matter?

[image: before collision]

[image: durin collision]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to know the coefficient of restitution to find the momentum that is transferred from $m_1$ to $m_2$ during the collision. To find the average normal force between the bodies during the collision you also need to know the duration of the collision, since the average force is the change in momentum of either body divided by the duration.

If the bodies are assumed to be perfectly rigid then the duration of the collision is zero and the normal force required to achieve an instantaneous change in momentum is infinite. In the real world, of course, the bodies will not be perfectly rigid, they will deform during the collision, and the collision will have a non-zero duration.

Answer (score 0):

A rigid body generates enough force to keep from being deformed. If $m_1$ and $m_2$ are pressed together, they press back just hard enough to keep from digging into each other. If you stop pressing, they stop pushing back. If you pull them apart, they don't pull to stick together.

Here, the table generates an upward force because gravity presses the masses down.

So to answer your question, you need to ask if they are being pressing the pressed together, or are they just sitting side by side.